# What happens before and after the first and last fan curve control points in MSI Click Bios's fan speed control UI?

Tags: bios, fan, cooling, windows-installer

The BIOS for my new motherboard has an advance feature where you can set fan speed thresholds, so the fan will go faster if the CPU is hot and slower when it's not. This is neat, and I basically understand it, but something is completely perplexing me and I can't find any guide which explains it. That is: what happens *off the ends  of the curve?*

If I set the first point as

Here's the UI in question.. first, what a curve looks like after you've created it:

[image: msi smart fan curve]

and here while configuring it (you can see the temps on the X axis):

[image: editing the curve]

Which I hope illustrate my puzzlement. I've found various guides and howtos, and none of them even mention this.

**If I set the first point at, for example, 33°C and 48%, *what happens when the temperature is below 33° C?*?**

If the answer is "that's the behavior *up until* 33°C", what happens at the other end of the line? If that's set to 90% and 90°C, is that the top speed ever, or does it go to full speed after that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a well-based answer (or an answer at all), as it's based on hints.
There is absolutely no documentation to be found that answers your question.

For temperatures below the first point : I believe that the fans do not start
before that point.

For temperatures above the last point : I believe that the fans stay at
that setting.
I base this on this
[post](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/msi-pro-z-690-p.377150/page-2)
from the MSI forums, where I found this advice :

> And for safety, make sure the last point of the fan curve is at 90°C and 100% fan speed.